# Toggle wireless hardware in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, power

I installed the windows 8 Release Preview and am quite happy with it.
The one thing that I miss is being able to turn off the wireless hardware which I could do with an application that came pre-installed with my laptop on windows 7.

This way I get significantly lesser battery life when on the move. Is there any way I can turn off my Wifi and Bluetooth in windows 8 and turn them on when required?

Comment: I am not aware of a single laptop that does not also have a hardware switch that disables the wireless card.

Comment: @Ramhound There are actually. I have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe **Airplane Mode** is what you're looking for.

Airplane mode disable all wireless network connections (e.g. Wi-Fi, mobile broadband, Bluetooth) at once. Turning Airplane Mode on will achieve the same result as turning off wireless hardware in your Windows 7 laptop.

[Here is a quick tutorial](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5355-airplane-mode-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) on how to toggle Airplane Mode in Windows 8 (Source: eightforums.com).